# Deallocate SKScene after transition to another SKScene in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, sprite-kit, deinit

I have a view controller that has three skscenes as children.

When I transition from one to another, the old skscene doesn't get deallocated.

I want it to get deallocated as if it was never there.

Example:

When I first load the app, only 1 skscene is visible (say it takes up 100mb memory), then I transition to another (100mb more), and then the third (300mb memory).

I would end up with 300mb memory and I want to have 100 at all times.

How can I achieve this?

```
My view controller: 

//
//  ViewController.m
//  Paddle Jumper
//
//  Created by Chance Daniel on 1/18/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Max Hudson. All rights reserved.
//

#import "Flurry.h"
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "startViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController{
    BOOL sceneSetUp;
}

- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
    if(!sceneSetUp){

        [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];

        // Configure the view.
        SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;
        //skView.showsFPS = YES;
        //skView.showsNodeCount = YES;

        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        if([[defaults objectForKey:@"firstTime"] intValue] != 1){
            [defaults setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] forKey:@"firstTime"];

            [defaults setObject:@"ggr" forKey:@"skinSelected"];
            [defaults setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2] forKey:@"ggrOwned"];

            [defaults setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:5000] forKey:@"gona"];
            [defaults setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1500] forKey:@"points"];
            [defaults setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:7] forKey:@"livesLeftValue"];
            [defaults setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:3] forKey:@"shieldsLeftValue"];
            [defaults setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2] forKey:@"lvlTwoLeftValue"];
            [defaults setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0] forKey:@"lvlThreeLeftValue"];
        }

        if(![defaults objectForKey:@"tut_game1"]){
            [defaults setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] forKey:@"tut_game1"];
            [defaults setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] forKey:@"tut_store"];
            [defaults setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] forKey:@"tut_daily"];
        }

        [defaults synchronize];

        // Create and configure the scene.
        SKScene * startScene = [StartViewController sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
        startScene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;

        // Present the scene.
        [skView presentScene:startScene];
        //[skView presentScene:scene];

        sceneSetUp = YES;
    }

}

-(void) switchScene{

}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
    } else {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
    }
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

@end

An SKScene that won't release: //
//  SettingsSKScene.m
//  Paddle Jumper
//
//  Created by Max Hudson on 3/15/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Max Hudson. All rights reserved.
//

#import "SettingsSKScene.h"
#import "gameViewController.h"
#import "StoreScene.h"

@interface SettingsSKScene (){
    SKSpriteNode *bg;
    SKSpriteNode *masterOverlay;
    SKSpriteNode *wbox;
    SKSpriteNode *gamecenter;
    SKSpriteNode *max;
    SKSpriteNode *chance;
    SKSpriteNode *bryce;
    SKSpriteNode *home;
    SKSpriteNode *play;

    SKSpriteNode *chance_link;
    SKSpriteNode *max_link;
    SKSpriteNode *bryce_link;

    SKSpriteNode *fbButton;
    SKSpriteNode *fbToggleYes;
    SKSpriteNode *fbToggleNo;

    SKLabelNode *story1;
    SKLabelNode *story2;
    SKLabelNode *story3;

    SKLabelNode *chance_name;
    SKLabelNode *max_name;
    SKLabelNode *bryce_name;

    SKLabelNode *chance_role;
    SKLabelNode *max_role;
    SKLabelNode *bryce_role;

    SKLabelNode *chance_handle;
    SKLabelNode *max_handle;
    SKLabelNode *bryce_handle;

    SKTexture *bg_texture;
    SKTexture *gamecenter_texture;
    SKTexture *wbox_texture;
    SKTexture *max_texture;
    SKTexture *chance_texture;
    SKTexture *bryce_texture;
    SKTexture *home_texture;
    SKTexture *play_texture;
    SKTexture *fb_texture;
    SKTexture *toggle_yes_texture;
    SKTexture *toggle_no_texture;
}

@end

@implementation SettingsSKScene

-(id) initWithSize:(CGSize)size{
    if(self = [super initWithSize:size]){
        masterOverlay = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor blackColor] size:self.frame.size];
        masterOverlay.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/2, self.frame.size.height/2);
        [self addChild:masterOverlay];

        bg_texture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"settings_bg"];
        wbox_texture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"white_rect_bg"];
        gamecenter_texture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"gc"];
        max_texture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"max"];
        chance_texture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"chance"];
        bryce_texture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"bryce"];
        home_texture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"home_light"];
        play_texture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"play_light"];
        fb_texture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"fb_light"];
        toggle_yes_texture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"toggle_yes"];
        toggle_no_texture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"toggle_no"];

        NSArray *to_preload = @[bg_texture, wbox_texture, gamecenter_texture, max_texture, chance_texture, bryce_texture, home_texture, play_texture, fb_texture, toggle_yes_texture, toggle_no_texture];

        [SKTexture preloadTextures:to_preload withCompletionHandler:^{
            [self fadeRemove:masterOverlay];
            [self initialize];
        }];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void) fadeRemove: (SKNode *) node{
    double duration = arc4random() % 10;
    duration *= 0.05;
    SKAction *fadeOut = [SKAction fadeOutWithDuration:0.1+duration];
    SKAction *remove = [SKAction runBlock:^{
        [node removeFromParent];
    }];

    [node runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[fadeOut, remove]]];
}

-(void) initialize{
    bg = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:bg_texture];
    bg.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/2, self.frame.size.height/2);
    bg.zPosition = 0;

    wbox = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:wbox_texture];
    wbox.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/2, 70);
    wbox.alpha = 0.8;
    wbox.zPosition = 2;

    gamecenter = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:gamecenter_texture];
    gamecenter.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/2 + 100, self.frame.size.height/2-2);
    gamecenter.name = @"gc";
    gamecenter.zPosition = 2;

    fbButton = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:fb_texture];
    fbButton.size = CGSizeMake(36, 36);
    fbButton.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/2 - 115, self.frame.size.height/2-2);
    fbButton.name = @"fb";
    fbButton.zPosition = 2;

    fbToggleNo = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:toggle_no_texture];
    fbToggleNo.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/2 - 50, self.frame.size.height/2-2);
    fbToggleNo.size = CGSizeMake(fbToggleNo.size.width/3, fbToggleNo.size.height/3);
    fbToggleNo.name = @"fbno";
    fbToggleNo.zPosition = 2;

    fbToggleYes = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:toggle_yes_texture];
    fbToggleYes.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/2 - 70, self.frame.size.height/2-2);
    fbToggleYes.name = @"fbyes";
    fbToggleYes.zPosition = 2;

    int hpBuffer = 40;
    int hpZ = 2;

    home = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:home_texture];
    home.position = CGPointMake(hpBuffer, self.frame.size.height - hpBuffer);
    home.zPosition = hpZ;
    home.name = @"home";

    play = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:play_texture];
    play.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width - hpBuffer, self.frame.size.height - hpBuffer);
    play.zPosition = hpZ;
    play.name = @"play";

    [self addChild:bg];
    [self addChild:wbox];
    [self addChild:gamecenter];
    [self addChild:home];
    [self addChild:play];

    [self addChild:fbButton];
    [self addChild:fbToggleNo];

    [self addCredits];
    [self addStory];
}

-(void) addCredits{
    /* images */

    int cmbZ = wbox.zPosition + 1;
    int cmbY = wbox.position.y;
    int cmbXUnit = 132;
    int cmbX = self.frame.size.width/2 - (3*cmbXUnit)/2 + 20;
    int cmbWidth = 40;

    chance  = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:chance_texture];
    max = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:max_texture];
    bryce  = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:bryce_texture];

    chance.zPosition = cmbZ;
    max.zPosition = cmbZ;
    bryce.zPosition = cmbZ;

    chance.position = CGPointMake(cmbX+cmbXUnit*0, cmbY+3);
    max.position = CGPointMake(cmbX+cmbXUnit*1 + 10, cmbY);
    bryce.position = CGPointMake(cmbX+cmbXUnit*2 + 10, cmbY+5);

    chance.size = CGSizeMake(cmbWidth, (chance.size.height/chance.size.width)*cmbWidth);
    max.size = CGSizeMake(cmbWidth, (max.size.height/max.size.width)*cmbWidth);
    bryce.size = CGSizeMake(cmbWidth, (bryce.size.height/bryce.size.width)*cmbWidth);

    [self addChild:chance];
    [self addChild:max];
    [self addChild:bryce];

    /* names */

    int cmb_nameXUnit = 30;
    int cmb_nameY = wbox.position.y - 10;
    int cmb_nameFontSize = 18;

    chance_name = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"BebasNeue"];
    max_name = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"BebasNeue"];
    bryce_name = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"BebasNeue"];

    chance_name.text = @"Chance Daniel";
    max_name.text = @"Max Hudson";
    bryce_name.text = @"Bryce Daniel";

    chance_name.fontColor = [SKColor blackColor];
    max_name.fontColor = [SKColor blackColor];
    bryce_name.fontColor = [SKColor blackColor];

    chance_name.horizontalAlignmentMode = SKLabelHorizontalAlignmentModeLeft;
    max_name.horizontalAlignmentMode = SKLabelHorizontalAlignmentModeLeft;
    bryce_name.horizontalAlignmentMode = SKLabelHorizontalAlignmentModeLeft;

    chance_name.position = CGPointMake(chance.position.x + cmb_nameXUnit, cmb_nameY);
    max_name.position = CGPointMake(max.position.x + cmb_nameXUnit, cmb_nameY);
    bryce_name.position = CGPointMake(bryce.position.x + cmb_nameXUnit, cmb_nameY);

    chance_name.fontSize = cmb_nameFontSize;
    max_name.fontSize = cmb_nameFontSize;
    bryce_name.fontSize = cmb_nameFontSize;

    chance_name.zPosition = cmbZ;
    max_name.zPosition = cmbZ;
    bryce_name.zPosition = cmbZ;

    [self addChild:chance_name];
    [self addChild:max_name];
    [self addChild:bryce_name];

    /* roles */

    int cmb_roleY = wbox.position.y - 25;
    int cmb_roleFontSize = 11;

    chance_role = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"BebasNeue"];
    max_role = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"BebasNeue"];
    bryce_role = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"BebasNeue"];

    chance_role.text = @"Programmer";
    max_role.text = @"Programmer";
    bryce_role.text = @"Graphic Designer";

    chance_role.fontColor = [SKColor darkGrayColor];
    max_role.fontColor = [SKColor darkGrayColor];
    bryce_role.fontColor = [SKColor darkGrayColor];

    chance_role.horizontalAlignmentMode = SKLabelHorizontalAlignmentModeLeft;
    max_role.horizontalAlignmentMode = SKLabelHorizontalAlignmentModeLeft;
    bryce_role.horizontalAlignmentMode = SKLabelHorizontalAlignmentModeLeft;

    chance_role.position = CGPointMake(chance.position.x + cmb_nameXUnit + 19, cmb_roleY);
    max_role.position = CGPointMake(max.position.x + cmb_nameXUnit + 12, cmb_roleY);
    bryce_role.position = CGPointMake(bryce.position.x + cmb_nameXUnit + 6, cmb_roleY);

    chance_role.fontSize = cmb_roleFontSize;
    max_role.fontSize = cmb_roleFontSize;
    bryce_role.fontSize = cmb_roleFontSize;

    chance_role.zPosition = cmbZ;
    max_role.zPosition = cmbZ;
    bryce_role.zPosition = cmbZ;

    [self addChild:chance_role];
    [self addChild:max_role];
    [self addChild:bryce_role];

    /* twitter handles */

    int cmb_handY = wbox.position.y - 40;
    int cmb_handFontSize = 10;

    chance_handle = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"BebasNeue"];
    max_handle = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"BebasNeue"];
    bryce_handle = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"BebasNeue"];

    chance_handle.text = @"@ChanceOfThat";
    max_handle.text = @"@max_hud";
    bryce_handle.text = @"@BryceOfLife";

    chance_handle.fontColor = [SKColor darkGrayColor];
    max_handle.fontColor = [SKColor darkGrayColor];
    bryce_handle.fontColor = [SKColor darkGrayColor];

    chance_handle.position = CGPointMake(chance.position.x, cmb_handY);
    max_handle.position = CGPointMake(max.position.x, cmb_handY);
    bryce_handle.position = CGPointMake(bryce.position.x, cmb_handY);

    chance_handle.fontSize = cmb_handFontSize;
    max_handle.fontSize = cmb_handFontSize;
    bryce_handle.fontSize = cmb_handFontSize;

    chance_handle.zPosition = cmbZ;
    max_handle.zPosition = cmbZ;
    bryce_handle.zPosition = cmbZ;

    [self addChild:chance_handle];
    [self addChild:max_handle];
    [self addChild:bryce_handle];

    /* touchzones */

    CGSize cmdL_size = CGSizeMake(120, 70);
    SKColor *cmdL_color = [SKColor clearColor];
    int cmdLZ = 3;
    int cmdLX = cmbX + 40;

    chance_link = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:cmdL_color size:cmdL_size];
    max_link = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:cmdL_color size:cmdL_size];
    bryce_link = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:cmdL_color size:cmdL_size];

    chance_link.position = CGPointMake(cmdLX+cmbXUnit*0, cmbY);
    max_link.position = CGPointMake(cmdLX+cmbXUnit*1 + 10, cmbY);
    bryce_link.position = CGPointMake(cmdLX+cmbXUnit*2 + 10, cmbY);

    chance_link.zPosition = cmdLZ;
    max_link.zPosition = cmdLZ;
    bryce_link.zPosition = cmdLZ;

    chance_link.name = @"c_handle";
    max_link.name = @"m_handle";
    bryce_link.name = @"b_handle";

    [self addChild:chance_link];
    [self addChild:max_link];
    [self addChild:bryce_link];
}

-(void) addStory{

    int stX = self.frame.size.width/2;
    int stZ = 2;
    SKColor *stColor = [SKColor whiteColor];

    story1 = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"BebasNeue"];
    story2 = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"BebasNeue"];
    story3 = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"BebasNeue"];

    story1.text = @"Gon";
    story2.text = @"Help Gon-Gon and his friends get";
    story3.text = @"Back to the time they came from!";

    story1.fontColor = stColor;
    story2.fontColor = stColor;
    story3.fontColor = stColor;

    story1.zPosition = stZ;
    story2.zPosition = stZ;
    story3.zPosition = stZ;

    story1.position = CGPointMake(stX, self.frame.size.height - 55);
    story1.fontSize = 50;

    story2.position = CGPointMake(stX, self.frame.size.height - 95);
    story2.fontSize = 30;

    story3.position = CGPointMake(stX, self.frame.size.height - 120);
    story3.fontSize = 20;

    [self addChild:story1];
    [self addChild:story2];
    [self addChild:story3];
}

-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UITouch *touchUI = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touchPoint = [touchUI locationInNode:self];
    SKNode *touchNode = [self nodeAtPoint:touchPoint];

    if([touchNode.name isEqualToString:@"home"]){
        StartViewController *svc = [[StartViewController alloc] initWithSize:self.size];
        SKTransition *fade = [SKTransition fadeWithColor :[SKColor blackColor] duration:0.4];
        [self.view presentScene:svc transition:fade];
    }

    if([touchNode.name isEqualToString:@"play"]){
        gameViewController *gvc = [[gameViewController alloc] initWithSize:self.size];
        SKTransition *fade = [SKTransition fadeWithColor :[SKColor blackColor] duration:0.4];
        [self.view presentScene:gvc transition:fade];
    }

    if([touchNode.name isEqualToString:@"gc"]){
        NSDictionary * dict = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithBool:1], @"showGC", nil];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:@"kNotificationUpdateBannerView" object:self userInfo:dict];
    }

    if([touchNode.name isEqualToString:@"c_handle"]){
        NSURL *urlApp = [NSURL URLWithString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"twitter:///user?screen_name=ChanceOfThat"]];
        int worked = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:urlApp];
        if(!worked){
            NSURL *urlApp = [NSURL URLWithString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"https://twitter.com/#!/ChanceOfThat"]];
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:urlApp];
        }
    }

    if([touchNode.name isEqualToString:@"m_handle"]){
        NSURL *urlApp = [NSURL URLWithString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"twitter:///user?screen_name=max_hud"]];
        int worked = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:urlApp];
        if(!worked){
            NSURL *urlApp = [NSURL URLWithString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"https://twitter.com/#!/max_hud"]];
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:urlApp];
        }
    }

    if([touchNode.name isEqualToString:@"b_handle"]){
        NSURL *urlApp = [NSURL URLWithString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"twitter:///user?screen_name=BryceOfLife"]];
        int worked = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:urlApp];
        if(!worked){
            NSURL *urlApp = [NSURL URLWithString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"https://twitter.com/#!/BryceOfLife"]];
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:urlApp];
        }
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: `sceneInstance = nil;` ?

Comment: Have 3 view controllers, one per scene?

Comment: show us the relevant bits of code. your scene is likely not deLlocating because you keep a strong reference to it in your viewcontroller

Comment: Okay, it doesn't look like you keep references in the view controller. Then I suspect your scene does not dealloc (override that method and set a breakpoint/log) because either something else has a strong reference to it, or you created a retain cycle (ie most common case: you keep a strong reference in a child node to a parent node).

Comment: Is there a good way to find the source of that? What might it look like?

Comment: @LearnCocos2D help please?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A similar problem was faced by the person who asked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19251337/ios-7-sprite-kit-freeing-up-memory).

When asked whether he was able to solve it, they said:

> Yes, I did, there wasn't anything I could do about it from the scene
>   or Sprite Kit for that matter, I simply needed to remove the scene and
>   the view containing it completely from the parent view, cut all its
>   bonds to the other parts of the system, in order for the memory to be
>   deallocated as well.

You should use separate views for each of your scene and transition between these views. You can follow these steps to make it look natural:

1 - At the point you want to transition from one scene to the other, take a snapshot of the scene using the following code:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, NO, scale);
[self drawViewHierarchyInRect:self.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Then, add this image as a subview of the SKView of the current scene, and remove the scene.

2 - Initialise the new scene on another view, and transition between the two views using UIView animation.

3 - Remove the first view from it's superview.

Answer (score 7):

I am just starting out with SpriteKit in Swift and I had the same problem: My intro scene was playing some music that I wanted to stop after transitioning to the main menu scene, and I figured the `deinit` would be a good place to put the `AVAudioPlayer.stop()` call in, but `deinit` was never being called.

After looking around I learned that it may be because of some strong references to the scene, so in my `GameViewController:UIViewController` subclass I changed this code:

```
let intro = IntroScene(size: skView.bounds.size)
skView.presentScene(intro)
```

to

```
skView.presentScene(IntroScene(size: skView.bounds.size))
```

and in the intro scene, that I wanted to be deallocated, I changed

```
let mainMenu  = MainMenuScene(size: self.size)
let crossFade = SKTransition.crossFadeWithDuration(1)

self.scene.view.presentScene(mainMenu, transition: crossFade)
```

to

```
self.scene.view.presentScene(MainMenuScene(size: self.size),
                             transition: SKTransition.crossFadeWithDuration(1))
```

and it worked! After the transition was complete the `deinit` method got called.

I assume that the outgoing scene was not being deinitialized because there were variables holding references to it.

Comment: This helped me 50%. After changing to `sceneView.presentScene(MyScene())` way of showing it as suggested in the answer it worked for one view controller but was not working in another. In both view controllers the SKView was a weak IBOutlet and exactly same scene was added exactly same way. Ended up adding `sceneView.presentScene(nil)` into `viewWillDisappear`, which made it correctly deallocate in both cases.

Answer (score 2):

**December 2019/Swift 5**

Update:

*My layout:*

I have a **single view controller** that contains **2 SKViews** which each of them have their own unique SKScene that are presented at the same time. One SKView & its SKScene is the main overworld where the player character is rendered, controlled, NPC's rendered, camera tracking, the whole shebang etc., & the other SKView & its SKScene display the mini map of the overworld.
You can imagine there are also quite a number of SKSpriteNode's & lot of them ALWAYS have some kind of SKAction/animation running non-stop (swaying trees for instance). My SKScenes even contain their own arrays pointing at specific groups of SKSpriteNodes, such as, character nodes, building nodes, tree nodes. This is for quick access & convenience purposes.
Plus, I have a few singletons that either contain an array of SKTextures, or character models, etc.. They are kept around as an optimization for quick data access rather than reading from disc/accessing storage every time I need something.
There are even UIKit elements used for the game UI inside the view controller.
Many other objects, such as, my models that contain data on characters, buildings, the entire game session all have some kind of delegates pointing at someone. On top of all of this the codebase is massive.

After observing memory in the debug session I found out the sure-fire way to make sure nothing is retained is to absolutely make sure the following:

*Memory handling:*

- Pass in nil for scene presentation & set that skview's property/pointer to nil as well
- Remove all view controller primary view subviews
- Absolutely set *every* **delegate** you have to nil !!!!!!!!!!!!!!
- Remove all observers IF you happen to have any
- Anywhere you have an array/dictionary or pointer to some kind of object YOU created, set it to nil/empty it
- **CRITICAL**: put all of the above into a single function/method & make sure to call it right before changing view controllers!

*NOTE: IF you have 1 view controller for the entire app (congrats on squeezing everything - youz overlord squeezer), then do NOT nil everything & use caution. BUT the previous scene still needs to be set to nil during presentation.

So something like this if you're jumping between view controllers:

```
/// Remove all pointers to any data, nodes & views.
fileprivate func cleanUp() {
    guard self.skView != nil else { return }
    // Session was passing data updates to this view controller; time to nil it
    self.gameSessionModel.delegate = nil
    self.skView.presentScene(nil)
    self.skViewMiniMap.presentScene(nil)
    self.skView = nil
    self.skViewMiniMap = nil
    for subview in self.view.subviews {
        subview.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}

/// Take the user back to the main menu module/view controller.
fileprivate func handleMenuButton() {
    // First, clean up everything
    self.cleanUp()
    // Then go to the other view controller
    let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainViewController")
    self.show(view, sender: .none)
}
```

Call `handleMenuButton()` function or whatever function you use to present another view controller, but make sure the `cleanUp()` function is called within it!
*NOTE: Classes such as 'gameSessionModel' are entirely my own custom classes. Xcode will throw an error on such things (unless you magically have the same one...) so delete such things. They are only used as example code in case you have delegates pointing at the current view controller.

If you're only presenting different SKScene's with a single SKView, then your `cleanUp()` function can end up being "lighter" as such:

```
/// Remove all pointers to any data, nodes & views.
fileprivate func cleanUp() {
    self.skView.presentScene(nil)
    // Previous scene was set to nil, its deinit called. Now onto the new scene:
    let gameScene = self.setupGameScene(id: "perhapsYouUseStringIDsToDisntiguishBetweenScenes?")
    self.skView.presentScene(gameScene)
}
```

*NOTE: Do NOT forget to use the SKScene's **deinit** method to remove anything you won't need. It's a practice I use all the time for **all** my classes to untangle anything I might have missed.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with SKScene or SKView, as long as I can see. Make sure the scene instance is not strongly reference anywhere else, especially inside a block. Blocks are highly probable to be ignored.

More about weak reference inside a block: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17105368/571489

As far as I see, you do have a block strongly referencing the scene instance:

```
[SKTexture preloadTextures:to_preload withCompletionHandler:^{
    [self fadeRemove:masterOverlay];
    [self initialize];
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: My previous idea about an NSTimer was irrelevant**

To make sure this is an issue isolated to this scene, override the dealloc methods of all scenes you might have (including this one) like this:

```
 -(void)dealloc {
  NSLog(@"Dealloc <scene name>");
 }
```

Look at your other scene transitions, see if they deallocate properly. Find the differences between these scenes. This will help you see if it's an isolated issue or a bigger problem. Once you have the problem fixed be sure to comment out or remove the dealloc method as it is overriding the one that actually deallocates the memory. Hopefully this helps!

Comment: dealloc is not getting called unfortunately

Comment: It wont get called while ARC is being used.

Comment: Actually, it will get called while ARC is in use. I successfully used this method to troubleshoot issues I was having with this.

Comment: Well it didn't get called

Comment: Which means you have a retain cycle somewhere. Build for instruments (cmd-I) and select allocations. Once the app starts, use the instruments search bar to find objects that might be your cause. Then modify the behavior of the object(s) as necessary.