# Custom SpriteKit "Door open", "Page Turn" transition

Tags: ios, ipad, ios7, sprite-kit

Is there any documentation or tutorials on creating custom transitions in SpriteKit?
Is there any way to modify `[SKTransition doorwayWithDuration:1];` to show only one door, and to open towards the user?

I found this project on github and modified it to use a single door. 
https://github.com/mkftr/DoorwayTransition
But this only works on Views. Not SKScene.

Is there a way to modify it so that I can get it to work?

I can't find anything out there, documentation or otherwise, explaining any of this. 
The transitions that come bundled in SpriteKit are too few, and I figured this would be a common problem for many other developers.

Failing all the above, what's the alternative?
I'm putting together an interactive book, and would really like a decent page turning transition between scenes.

Note though, I'm not looking for "Page Curl", but more of a "Door opening" transition.
But will settle for "Page Curl" if necessary, and someone can explain how to do it.

The book will only be available on iPad.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very good page flip controller you can customize to create a door type book flip:

https://github.com/mpospese/MPFoldTransition

However, this also only works on views. But, you can use that to your advantage.

Since a SKScene is rendered on a SKView (which is a subclassed UIView), you can show each scene on a different SKView and use the flip transition in between each instance.

Comment: multiple SKView on iOS are problematic as only one updates in realtime

Comment: @LearnCocos2D so what's another alternative to get this working?
Could I create my own with CIFilters?

Comment: @LearnCocos2D I am using another SKView on a viewController as a form sheet which appears on top of the running instance. It does not stop the presenting viewController's SKView from rendering.

Comment: @BeauYoung please look at this answer also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22528395/2043580.