# Swift: Deallocate GameScene after transition to new scene?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

So I've read several questions on this but most are in Objective-C and I haven't found any that address/answer this directly. 
I am new to programming here so please explain any suggestions really thoroughly.

I need to understand how to **deallocate** my GameScene after game over is reached. The reason I need to do this is because after game over, I transition to a new SKScene (the game over scene) and when I transition back to my GameScene, either GameScene is not reset entirely or I'm generating a new GameScene each time.

I say this because My frames per second count goes down every time I get game over and transition back to the GameScene, so that if I do it enough times I can't even play the game anymore. This is a problem.

I don't understand why this happens because when I transition to my game over scene, I remove everything from my GameScene:

```
self.viewController!.performSegueWithIdentifier("goToGameOver", sender: nil)
            self.removeAllChildren()
            self.removeAllActions()
            self.scene?.removeFromParent()
```

I also read here: [After Closing SKScene, Memory Remains High](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22704219/after-closing-skscene-memory-remains-high) that removing the SKView that contains an SKScene deallocates the SKScene, so when both my GameScene and game over scenes are left, I remove BOTH views from their superviews like this:

```
override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {
        print("its gone")

        self.view.removeFromSuperview()

    }
```

But nothing has any affect on the decreasing frames per second count and the game keeps lagging. I don't understand what I'm not doing and can't tell whether the game over scene is the problem or I'm just not deallocating GameScene.

How do I deallocate the GameScene? What else should I be doing?

EDIT:

My node count and draws count remain about the same every time I transition back to GameScene, so that doesn't seem to be a problem. I tried testing whether `deinit` was called when transitioning between scenes (I didn't have a `deinit` before) using this within the GameScene class:

```
} //<**End of GAMESCENE**

    deinit {
        print("Deinit was called")
    }
```

And nothing is printed so `deinit` is not being called.

EDIT 2:

@alex_p Here is what I have in my GameViewController-

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController, SKProductsRequestDelegate, SKPaymentTransactionObserver {

    var scene1: GameScene?
    var scene2: GameScene?
    var skView: SKView?

// Action to present next Scene
    @IBAction func nextSceneAction(sender: AnyObject) {
        print("Next scene")
        // Create new GameScene object
        scene2 = GameScene(fileNamed:"GameScene")
        // Present scene2 object that replace the scene1 object
        skView!.presentScene(scene2) //ERROR ON THIS LINE
        scene1 = nil
    }
```

And I call this method from my GameScene like this:

```
self.viewController.nextSceneAction(self)
```

I copied yours exactly but I am receiving the error `unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` on the line commented on above. Deinit in not being called.

Comment: You can start with overriding deinit in scenes. See if it is called when transitioning between scenes. That would be a start. If deinit isn't called, then you have to search for possible retain cycles. Also check nodes count and draws count. Can you update your question with those data ?

Comment: Just updated. I don't think deinit is being called so how does one search for a retain cycle?

Comment: Yeah, you have probably some strong references to the scene ... To start take a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19251337/ios-7-sprite-kit-freeing-up-memory/19253739#19253739 . After that check out terms called "unowned self" and "weak self" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24320347/shall-we-always-use-unowned-self-inside-closure-in-swift/24320474#24320474 Hope this will take you somewhere.

Comment: Also if I recall correctly, showsNodesCount will show the number of nodes which are currently drawn, not the offscreen nodes. Offscreen nodes are not removed automatically and even if not drawn, they are still in there, in a node tree. This can cause a lag. You can try to enumerate through all nodes inside node three by passing this string  //* as a node name. Read more here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/25749743/3402095

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my project, I used the following mechanism and it worked well. All my scenes `SKScene` objects were optional variables. When i need the new scene to show, i create it and present at `SKView`. When i need to display the new scene, I set the previous object scene object to `nil`, this immediately reducing the reference count by 1, and becouse of at this moment no one object is not use my scene, the reference count becomes zero and scene was deleted.

The `SKScene` object is a ordinary class object and `ARC` works with them like with all reference type objects. You only need to monitor the number of references to the scene. All are finished with the various resources I was start in `deinit` of `SKScene` object

The simple example:

At `UIViewController` we have optional objects of `GameScene`:

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {
    var scene1: GameScene?
    var scene2: GameScene?
    var skView: SKView?
    
    // Action to present next Scene
    @IBAction func nextSceneAction(sender: AnyObject) {
        print("Next scene")
        // Create new GameScene object
        scene2 = GameScene(fileNamed:"GameScene")
        // Present scene2 object that replace the scene1 object
        skView!.presentScene(scene2)
        scene = nil
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Create GameScene object
        scene = GameScene(fileNamed:"GameScene")
        skView = (self.view as! SKView)
        skView!.showsFPS = true
        skView!.showsNodeCount = true

        skView!.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
        
        scene!.scaleMode = .AspectFill
        
        // Present current scene
        skView!.presentScene(scene)
    }
}
```

At `GameScene` in `deinit` print some text to show that it object will be deleted:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
   ...
    
    deinit {
        print("Deinit scene")
    }
}
```

Debug output after push the `nextSceneAction` button:

> Next scene
>
> Deinit scene

Comment: That sounds like a good idea. Could you provide an example of this in your code? Like how and where to set the SKScene to an optional variable and then set this to nil when displaying the new scene? Sorry I'm new to this

Comment: Add abstract example to answer

Comment: I updated my question. I tried your code but received the error "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" when trying to present scene2. How can I fix this?

Comment: @skyguy post your all code from 'GameViewController', where you create the 'skView'

Comment: Never mind I'm not having that issue anymore. Now my problem is that I'm still having the memory issue. When I test it on a device, after a few times around the lagging comes back and I'm back to where I started. Deinit is not being called. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: very hard to say what you doing wrong just not seeing the entire code

Comment: Never mind sorry. Didn't use exactly what you did but you got me to the solution. Thanks!