# Swift iOS: Memory leaks with the following code (video player)

Tags: ios, swift, memory, memory-leaks

I play a full screen video with a perpetual loop in my game (for the background). It works well but when I change the view, I get memory leaks identified with Instruments (Memory leaks template) on this code:

```
urlStr = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Video_Socle", ofType: "mov")
    let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: urlStr!)

    player = AVPlayer(URL: url)

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName(AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification, object: player!.currentItem, queue: nil)
    { notification in
        let t1 = CMTimeMake(5, 100);
        self.player!.seekToTime(t1)
        self.player!.play()

    }

    videoNode = SKVideoNode(AVPlayer: player!)
    videoNode!.anchorPoint = CGPointMake (0,0)
    videoNode!.size = CGSize(width: 2048, height: 1536)
    videoNode!.zPosition = 0


    background.addChild(videoNode!)
    if synch == false { video_synchronization()
    }
    videoNode!.play()
```

I have created a small cleaning function called when I change my view with the following code:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
player = nil
videoNode = nil

background.removeAllActions()
background.removeAllChildren()

let transition = SKTransition.revealWithDirection(.Right, duration: 2)
        let nextScene = MainView(size: scene!.size)
        nextScene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
        scene?.view?.presentScene(nextScene, transition: transition)

        self.viewController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

I get memory leaks identified  on the AVPlayer and SKVideoNode. Something strange is the leaks disapear when I remove the part:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName(AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification, object: player!.currentItem, queue: nil)
{ notification in
    let t1 = CMTimeMake(5, 100);
    self.player!.seekToTime(t1)
    self.player!.play()
}
```

What am I missing with this code ? Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

when you are changing the view you need to do the following..

If you have any view on which you are playing video .. You need to remove it.

`view.removeFromSuperView()`

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that. I have added your line just before the screen transition, in my cleaning function but I get a black screen. Where should be put: view.removeFromSuperView()

Comment: next time once you back to the same screen you need to addsubView() same. In short you need to add playerView in viewWillAppear() method. remove from superview should put in viewWillDisappear().

Comment: I'm getting memory leaks without changing views when attempting to loop an SKVideoNode in the same fashion you are.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and fixed it by removing the views as suggested then also setting the views to nil. Also be sure to pause the avplayer and set that to nil as well.