# self inside block called by super

Tags: objective-c, self, weak-references, retain-cycle

In this case, weakself is needed to avoid retain cycle

```
[self showMethodA:^{
    [weakself showMethodB];
}];
```

Will this case cause a retain cycle?

```
[super showMethodA:^{
    [self showMethodB];
}];
```

Answer (score 3):

Does it create a cycle? Only if showMethodA stores the block into self.

"super" vs. "self" only affects the dispatching, calling the superclass showMethodA instead of self's own showMethodA. It doesn't affect cycles. And whether a cycle is created or not depends on the code in showMethodA.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it will create retain cycle.

You only create a retain cycle if you actually store the block (because self points to the block, and block points to self).

Refer below link for more info :

[Referring to weak self inside a nested block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17104634/referring-to-weak-self-inside-a-nested-block)

Comment: Please show me where self points to the block in the code that we see.